# Sara loved to read or sara loved reading?

Tags: grammar

Plz, check expirations below

> ‎Sara loved to read

is grammatically correct but would it be incorrect if we say it

> sara loved reading

**read** in first expiration is verb I think but secound one is noun obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case both are acceptable.

The word "reading" can be understood as a noun, but most people would call it a "gerund" as it could take an object "Sara likes reading the newspaper"

In general some situations require an infinitive, some require a gerund, and in others both are acceptable.